# How do I configure Struts 2 to return a generated PDF?

Tags: struts2

```
<action name="trial_employee" 
        class="parity.action.TrialPrintEmployeeCopyAction">
  <result>/protected/trial_employee.pdf</result>
</action>
```

I've got an action class that generates a PDF file for download. How do I configure the action result to return the PDF?

The above doesn't work, it gives me a 404 error because the pdf isn't physically on the drive, it's being generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

If it is being generated dynamically you can return it as a stream something like

```
<result name="pdf  File" type="stream">
<param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
</result>
```

more details are here

[Stream result](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html)

Comment: It doesn't matter how it's being generated, you can stream off the filesystem as well.

Comment: @Dave:Agree!!! i suggested this way since if file is being generated on the file system we can use other way around

Comment: yea, unfortunately the morons that developed this thing originally have it generating 5 to 15 meg PDF files in memory and streaming them from memory.  all im allowed to do is convert it to struts2.  i figured out how to do it with a byte array but its ugly.  very very ugly.